# Why am I getting a broken image icon?

Tags: node.js, database, express, server, ejs

I'm trying to display all images in my database on an ejs page. I saved their URL's to a post table. The ejs page currently displays a broken image icon. Is there anything wrong with either of these? Do I need to iterate through them? The IMG URLs are stored in a table called posts

Here is an example url for an image:

```
https://res.cloudinary.com/zfinnan/image/upload/v1607108641/q4kyfxxkbf5waxgcrznd.png
```

Here is my route:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  db.post.findAll()
  .then((posts) => {
    const postArray = posts.map(post => {
      return post.get();
    })
    res.render('index', { image: post.image_url });
  })
});
```

Here is my index.ejs page:

```
<img width="500px" height="500px" src="<%= image %>" alt="uploaded image">
```

Comment: your `post` object doesn't exist outside the `posts` loop, you need to handle this, you can put the render inside the `posts.map` or you can use your `postArray` to get the image URL to render the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `post` object doesn't exist outside the `posts` loop, you need to handle this, you can put the render inside the `posts.map` or you can use your `postArray` to get the image URL to render the image

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  db.post.findAll()
  .then((posts) => {
    const postArray = posts.map(post => {
      return post.get();
    })
    // I am assuming you need only one and the first post instance contains that image URL
    res.render('index', { image: postArray[0].image_url });
  })
});
```